# How to change button image color in windows universal app using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

As in iOS, I can use setTintColor on UIButton, it will change the color of text and icon (png). But I cannot find similar method when I am working on windows universal app.

I tried some approaches to change the pixel colors of the PNG file, but it does not work for me, the BitmapImage becomes empty after this. What's wrong with the code or is there any other solutions which I am not aware of? I am new to windows development, hope someone can offer help. Thanks in advance.

```
    public async void LoadIconWithColor(string name, SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(this.IconsUri, name);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(uri);
        int height = 28; // the pixelHeight not working as well
        int width = 30;

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

        using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);

            using (var buffer = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                Byte[] pixels = new Byte[4 * width * height];
                buffer.Read(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {

                    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    {
                        int index = ((y * width) + x) * 4;

                        Byte b = pixels[index + 0];
                        Byte g = pixels[index + 1];
                        Byte r = pixels[index + 2];
                        Byte a = pixels[index + 3];

                        pixels[index + 0] = color.Color.B;
                        pixels[index + 1] = color.Color.G;
                        pixels[index + 2] = color.Color.R;
                        pixels[index + 3] = a;
                    }
                }

                buffer.Position = 0;
                buffer.Write(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pixels);
                image.SetSource(ms.AsRandomAccessStream());
            }
        }

        // the image become blank
    }
```

Comment: In order to show an icon with a changeable color you may better use a Path element instead of an Image. The Path has a `Data` property, which holds the Geometry of the Icon, and a `Fill` property for the fill brush, which you could assign a SolidColorBrush.

Comment: @Clemens does that mean I need to draw the icon with code? How can I get path info from the PNG file?

Comment: Not necessarily. You may use a design tool like [Expression Blend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294770.aspx).

Comment: @codingrhythm I am facing same issue, did you got some approach to change color of image?